# error on running mongodb on linux server

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am trying to run the command:

```
mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath data --logpath logs/mongo.log
```

in a linux server but it gives me the error

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

when I try to see the dependences of the file mongod with `readelf -d` it gives too many errors:

```
readelf: Warning: The e_shentsize field in the ELF header is larger than the size of an ELF section header
readelf: Error: Reading 0x9c00000 bytes extends past end of file for section headers
```

I didn't find any information about this error

Comment: How did you get the binary? Is it from your distro repository?

Comment: Yes It is on mongodb downleaded files

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on linux versions I was working with mongodb 32bit in my linux server 64bit